# How to send data in real-time between two separate components without navigation in React Native?

Tags: react-native

**`Feed` Screen**

```
<WriterBox
  writerAvatar={feed?.user?.avatar}
  writerName={feed?.user?.name}
  writeTime={feed?.createdAt}
  editTime={feed?.updatedAt}
  feedId={feed?.id}
  writerId={feed?.user?.id}
/>
```

**`WriterBox` Component**

```
  const deleteClick = () => {};

      <SmallBtn
        text={"삭제"}
        color={"main"}
        pressFunction={deleteClick}
      />
    </View>
```

So I have WriterBox component in Feed screen.

And in WriterBox Component, I have a `SmallBtn`.

I want to inform Feed screen to show alert when I click SmallBtn of WriterBox without navigating to Feed screen.

Usually we handle this with `useState`.

But this is separate component, so I can't send this data from WriterBox to Feed.

---

**AsyncStorage** is not possible to keep eye on the change of state.

So Feed screen can't respond `in real-item` with AsyncStorage.

How to deal this this case?

Comment: Maybe context can solve this issue?

Comment: @caslawter can you show me a brief example how to use context?

Answer (score 1):

you can pass a handler method to the WriterBox component.

```
const FeedScreen = () => {

    const handlDeletePress = () => {
      // do something in the feed screen
    }
    
    return (
        <WriterBox
          writerAvatar={feed?.user?.avatar}
          writerName={feed?.user?.name}
          writeTime={feed?.createdAt}
          editTime={feed?.updatedAt}
          feedId={feed?.id}
          writerId={feed?.user?.id}
          onDeletePress={handlDeletePress}
         />
     );
}

const WriterBox = props => {
    const deleteClick = () => {
      props.onDeletePress();
    };
    
    return (
        <SmallBtn
          text={"삭제"}
          color={"main"}
          pressFunction={deleteClick}
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: should I put props as argument? now I already get some props in WriterBox like `export default function WriterBox({
  feedId,
  writerAvatar,
  writerName,
  writeTime,
  writerId,
}) {...}` -> then how can I put props here?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking? all your props are in the `WriterBox` component. you can destructure props like this.

`const {feedId,   writerAvatar,   writerName,   writeTime,   writerId} = props`

is that what are you asking?

Comment: I need to send data forth and back: (1) WriterBox -> Feed "I press Delete" (2) Feed: press 'confirm delete' (3) Feed -> WriterBox " I press Confirm Delete" .
Is this logic possible through your answer?

Comment: Yes, pass as arguments to the `onDeletePress ` and you can get the data from handlDeletePress method.

Comment: my vscode says when I ` props.onDeletePress();` , Could not find name 'props'. Did you mean 'Props'? -> and Props also doesn't work.

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot of your code? or paste the code snippet here? To have a better look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246695/discussion-between-chari-and-hyejung).